# Pandas - count distinct values per column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Id ActivityId ActivityCode

1   2           3
1   2           4
1   3           2
```

I need to get a count of the distinct Activity IDs that the Id is related to.

In the example above, id 1 would return 2 since there're 2 distinct activity ids for that id.

The SQL would look this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ActivityId) FROM table GROUP BY Id
```

How do I do this in pandas?

(And if possible, I'd like to know if there's a way to get the result in a dictionary, without iterating manually)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) :

```
print (df)
   Id  ActivityId  ActivityCode
0   1           2             3
1   1           2             4
2   1           3             2
3   2           8             7

df = df.groupby('Id')['ActivityId'].nunique()
print (df)
Id
1    2
2    1
Name: ActivityId, dtype: int64
```

And for `dict` add [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.groupby('Id')['ActivityId'].nunique().to_dict()
print (d)
{1: 2, 2: 1}
```

Comment: Glad can help, good luck!