# Get len(unique()) for each distinct value as key in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I just started working with python pandas and am trying to achieve the following:

I have a dataframe `d` that contains the rows `Country` and `Botnet`. For each value of `Country`, I want to calculate how many distinct `Botnet` values exist.

I know that I can receive the distinct country values as follows:

```
d['Country'].unique()
```

I do not know however how I can now transform this to receive the length of all the unique botnet values sorted per country. Is this even possible in Pandas?

Comment: `df.groupby('Country')['Botnet'].nunique()`?

Comment: I think you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44301670/2901002)